# How to test validity of an environment variable with bash checking if it exists and is is true?

Tags: bash

I am looking for a test that would return `true` if the environment variable is defined and has a value different than `0`, `false` or `NULL`.

```
ENABLE_SOMETHING=1
# or ENABLE_SOMETHING=true

if ... do ...
```

Note: under no circumstance the bash should complain about the variable not being defined or having a weird value, anything else than 0, empty, false, or not defined would be considered true.

Comment: Not sure it can be done with less than 4 tests (according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228544/how-to-tell-if-a-string-is-not-defined-in-a-bash-shell-script ).

Answer (score 3):

Such a test does not exist as it might in a high-level language such as Java or C#, but it is relatively easy to construct.

Three comments on your question as asked:

1: You do not work with literal "true"/"false" values in bash; all commands and conditional constructs yield an **exit status**, or *logical result*, which is either 0 (true) or non-0 (false).
Work with this, don't try to re-invent the wheel.

2: Try not to use upper-case parameter names unless they are environment variables; this is a simple convention that helps keep your code clean.

3: What, exactly, do you mean by "NULL"? The literal string **NULL**, an empty value, or something else?
The latter two concepts don't exist in bash; a *NULL* variable would be unset, which you're already checking for.

The most effective solution would be a function that accepts a variable (or parameter, as bash calls them), and checks for those conditions, then sets the exit status based on that, effectively condensing multiple truth values to a literal 0 or 1.

For example:

`is_true() { if [[ "$1" = 0 ]]; then false; elif [[ -z "$1" ]]; then false; elif [[ "$1" =~ [Ff][Aa][Ll][Ss][Ee] ]]; then false; fi; }`

- `is_true "1"` yields 0, which is true
- `is_true "false"` yields 1, which is false
- `a=10; is_true "$a"` yields 0
- `grep -q something somefile` yields 0 if `something` appears at least once in `somefile`.

NOTE that the latter example clearly shows that you don't NEED such a construct; everything that happens in bash ***already*** works with these basic 0/1 truth values.

But I'll grant that you might have to convert input from some gnarly external program :)

Comment: NULL as in empty.

Comment: In that case you may have to add an explicit check to see if it is unset, in addition to the other 3.

Answer (score 3):

I find these comparisons unuseful because they make appearance of code obscur and unobvious. I just use the nice feature of bash, that comes since v4.2, from the manpage:

```
   -v varname
          True if the shell variable varname is set (has been assigned a value).
```

Usage is very simple

```
OUTPUT_TO_LOG=1
if [ -v OUTPUT_TO_LOG ]; then
    exec > &>./logfile
    …
fi
```

In other words, to flag as enabled, just define. Try it!

```
$ :() { if [ -v VAR ]; then echo 'existed'; fi }
$ unset VAR && :          # no output
$ unset VAR && VAR= && :  # "existed"
$ unset VAR && VAR=1 && : # "existed"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do all three checks with regular expression matching (undefined parameters resolve to the empty string):

```
is_true() (
  shopt -s nocasematch
  [[ ! $1 =~ ^(false|0|)$ ]]
)
```

Comment: An empty parameter is not the same as an unset parameter - but for the purposes of equality, they behave the same.

Comment: Modified the statement.

Comment: Function definition should be sub-shelled (parentheses instead of braces), otherwise `shopt` also changes the option in the callers environment. See my question about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179633/make-shopt-change-local-to-function).

Comment: I did not know that one, interesting.